# Is there a way to determine what the URL is for the environment in Tomcat on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Each Elastic Beanstalk environment has an associated URL (on the Elastic Load Balancer with the environment). In the Java/Tomcat flavor of EB, is there a way to query that URL, so it can be used dynamically within the application?

My current workaround is to pass the URL in as a parameter to the container, but that doesn't work nicely when switching environment URLs for live deployment.

Comment: At what point in your application's lifecycle do you need said URL? If it's in response to a client request, you could manipulate what you get from [HttpServletRequest#getRequestURL()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL()) or and similar APIs?

Comment: The URL is just <app>.elasticbeanstalk.com isn't it? Could you construct it from the application name?

Comment: @Charlie I suppose that could work for responses, but I actually need it before then for configuration as well. Seems like there should be a way for EB to pass this kind of config data either into the JVM or Tomcat container.

Comment: @Christopher Sadly, that would not work if you're running with a custom URL (which is required for HTTPS)

Comment: @bmajz If it's HTTPS you're uploading a cert to the ELB, yeah? Could you ping the certs configured on the ELB? That should be available at configuration time.

Comment: @Christopher haven't been able to find out how to do that either

Comment: @bmajz Subsequent API calls (I guess; it's not a good solution): 1) grab instance ID, 2) query AWS CLI tools for instance's ELB, 3) query ELB for certs with AWS CLI tools... really not elegant; just trying to think of any way to do it

Comment: @Charlie if you can post your comment as an answer, I'll go ahead and accept it. I was actually able to use it to more-or-less meet my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does.

The Backend Loadbalancer forwards additional URLs when being called.

Check the Request Headers "Host", and "X-Forwarded-Host"

Answer (score 0):

As requested from the comments: At what point in your application's lifecycle do you need said URL? If it's in response to a client request, you could manipulate what you get from [HttpServletRequest#getRequestURL()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29) or and similar APIs?

(I'm curious what additions to this you used to meet your needs)

Comment: You might need this when doing something like generating an RSS feed in a batch job (i.e. not in response to a request).